# Cannot read property 'value' of undefined REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Counter extends Component {
  render() {
    this.schimbareCuloare();

    //React.createElement("div");
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
        <span className={this.schimbareCuloare()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
        <button
          onClick={() => this.props.onIncrement(this.props.counter)}
          className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
        >
          {" "}
          Incrementare{" "}
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(this.props.id)}
          className="button btn btn-danger btn-sm m-2"
        >
          Sterge
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  schimbareCuloare() {
    let classes = "badge m-2 badge-";
    classes += this.props.counter.value === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";
    return classes;
  }

  formatCount() {
    const { value } = this.props.counter;
    return value === 0 ? "Zero" : value;
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

So i have the error code "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
Counter.schimbareCuloare
C:/Users/Alex/counter-app2/src/components/counter.jsx:31" .
Line 31 is `classes += this.props.counter.value === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";` in the `schimbareCuloare` function

Can it be related to the fact that the state is a local property and the props global? I learn during this period to react and I don't know exactly what needs to change

Comment: Could you show parent component of Counter?

Comment: The error message says that it occurs at line 31. It would probably be helpful if you say which line this is

Comment: Are you passing in any props when using the Counter component?

Comment: @A_A line 31 isthe first time this.props is called in the code....

Comment: 31 line is this          classes += this.props.counter.value === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";

Answer (score 0):

This demo about how to handle props from parent Counter. Hope it helpful.

```
class Counter extends Component {
    render() {
        this.schimbareCuloare();

        //React.createElement("div");
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
                <span className={this.schimbareCuloare()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
                <button
                    onClick={() => this.props.onIncrement(this.props.counter)}
                    className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                >
                    {" "}
                    Incrementare{" "}
                </button>
                <button
                    onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(this.props.id)}
                    className="button btn btn-danger btn-sm m-2"
                >
                    Sterge
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }

    schimbareCuloare() {
        let classes = "badge m-2 badge-";
        classes += this.props.counter.value === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";
        return classes;
    }

    formatCount() {
        const { value } = this.props.counter;
        return value === 0 ? "Zero" : value;
    }
}


class Counters extends Component {
    state = {
        counters: [
            { id: 1, value: 5 },
            { id: 2, value: 0 },
            { id: 3, value: 0 },
            { id: 4, value: 0 }
        ]
    };

    handleDelete = counterId => {
        const counters = this.state.counters.filter(c => c.id !==
            counterId);
        this.setState({ counters });
    };

    handleReset = () => {
        const counters = this.state.counters.map(c => {
            c.value = 0;
            return c;
        });
        this.setState ({ counters });
    };

    handleIncrement = counter => {
        const counters = [...this.state.counters];
        const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
        counters[index].value = counters[index].value+ 1;
        this.setState({ counters });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button
                    onClick={this.handleReset}
                    className="btn btn-primary btn-sm m-2"
                >
                    Reset
                </button>

                {this.state.counters.map(counter => (
                    <Counter
                        id={counter.id}
                        onDelete={this.handleDelete}
                        counter={counter}
                        onIncrement={this.handleIncrement}
                    />
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```